# Double Quote and backslashes JSON reply

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Using an API provided by a supplier I've got a JSON reply formatted like that :

```
{"d":"{\"IdProduct\":0,\"Status\":0,\"Errors\":[\"B_MESSAGE_INVALID_REQUIRED_FIELDS\"]}"}
```

That causing in issue when trying to deserialize with JMS (PHP) because content of d is not considered as an object but a string.

I have tried creating json from PHP with array and json_encode() and everything works great with deserialize method :

```
{"d":{"IdProduct":123456,"Status":1,"Errors":["B_MESSAGE_INVALID_REQUIRED_FIELDS"]}}
```

Is it possible to remove useless backslashes and quotes from my side? Seems supplier can not change format.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API returns *a JSON string encoded into a JSON object*. Meaning, you first need to decode the "outer" object, then JSON-decode the `$obj['d']`, because it's a JSON string.

```
json_decode(json_decode($json)->d)
```

Obviously somebody should fix the API to not return double-encoded JSON.